# fixed button in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want a button to be fixed in its position, but the fact is I don't know the position of button, I mean I created a page where I placed a button (i.e **I didn't fixed its height or width**), what I want where ever in the page that button is created, on scrolling its position remains the fixed.

```
<table width='100%' border='1'>
   <tr><td><input type='submit' value='LogOut'></td></tr>
</table>
```

Now I don't know where this **submit** button will be **displayed** but I want that it should be in place where it is created.

Now I am using this code for making three buttons as fixed, but their left property is **auto** making them to overlap each other.

```
$('#headerHome,#headerAccount,#btnSignOut').button().each(function(){
    alert(''+$(this).css('left'));
  //$(this).css({
  //  'position' : 'fixed',
  //  'top': "'"+ $(this).css('top') +"'",
  //  'left': "'"+ ($(this).css('left')-100) +"'",
  //  'z-index' : '100'
  //});
});
```

Please shed some light.Thanks in advance.

**PS. I am using JQuery**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourButtonId').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: $('#yourButtonId').position().top,
        left: $('#yourButtonId').position().left
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks @davids, this is the code I am looking for but here what happens is that $('#yourButtonId').position().top returns the top on the basis of window, my button is inside a div is there any method to get the position of button with respect to the div.

Comment: According to the Jquery API, the 'position' method retrieves the coordinates of the element relative to its parent offset (http://api.jquery.com/position/). There's another method that gets the coordinates respect the document, which is 'offset' (http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Answer (score 3):

just add the css below... no need to go for jquery to place the div on a fixed position on a page.

```
table input[type=submit]
{
position:fixed;
top:150px;
}
```

hope this helps